# JQuery Fade-in onscroll problems

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, fadein

I have been trying to resolve this problem for several hours.

I would like to Fadein a div on scroll.

Then I would like to set up a rule for disabling that effect on Mobile devices.

This is my code

```
<style>
#conteneur5 { 
height:220px; 
width:1080px; 
background:#EFEFEF
;} 
</style>    

<body>
<div class="wow"> 
<div id="conteneur5">
<table width="1065" height="195"></table> 
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).scroll(function() { 
if (screen.width > 770) { 
$('.wow').hide(); } 
else { 

$('.wow').show();
}
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 130) {
$('.wow').fadeIn();
} else {
$('.wow').fadeOut();
}
});
</script>
```

I have tried many different combinations but none worked.

With the above sequence the Fadein works but the div is first visible then fadeout on scroll then fadein.

I tried to add display:none in css inline as I've read on another topic. But with no result.

My attempt to disable the effect on mobile is not working neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/166/

```
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="content">
    FADEIN
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
    $(window).resize(function() {        
        myFunction();
    });

    function myFunction() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        console.log(width);
        console.log((width > 770));
        if (width > 770) {
            $(document).on('scroll', function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 130) {
                    $('.content').fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.content').hide();
            $(document).unbind('scroll');
        }
    }

});

.space {
    height: 200px;
}
.content {
    display:none;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
body {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! The element is fading in properly now.
I need to set again the Fadeout property if the user scroll back to the top. Could you tell me the easiest way to achieve this ?

About the mobile display it still isn't working. I just want to disable the Fadein effect on mobile. In other words the element should display just normally.

Thanks and sorry my grammar.

Comment: Thanks for your AWESOMENESS ! I still have a lot to learn.
Thanks.

Comment: sounds good! gl on your project. oh and if the answer works, could you accept it, so as to help other people who look at the question? also, for those looking to answer unanswered questions wont waste time. thanks!